# multiplexer resistance increasing is that means its dying?

Tags: resistance

I have a multiplexer 16 channels for arduino  suddenly its stop working and when i measured this with multimeter each pin from mux produce 2k ohm, and when i measured this with arduino pin it measure no resistence at all.  is that mean it is dying? or the arduino is dying what is the sign that my mux is broken ?

Comment: Do you have a part number? A datasheet?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the EE.SE: what is the load of your MUX? Could you provide a simple schematic, for example using Circuit Lab as offered by the community?

Comment: If you edit your question, there is a circuit editor on this site.  You are asking a very specific question and we have no frame of reference for answers.  Guessing is not productive.  Edit your question, adding a circuit of relevant circuitry the mux is connected to and answer questions in the comments.  Please!